# baking a cookie with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cookie").text("expanded");
    //panel toggle
    $(".btn-slide").click(function() {
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        //set the name and value of the cookie
        $.cookie('panel', 'collapsed');
        $("#cookie").text("collapsed");
    }, function() {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        //set the name and value of the cookie
        $.cookie('panel', 'expanded');
        $("#cookie").text("expanded");
    });
    // cookie
    var panel = $.cookie('panel');
    // Set the user's selection for the state
    if (panel == 'collapsed') {
        $("#panel").hide();
    };
});
```

> **[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yomoore/RJMhT/138/)**

I don't see anyting wrong, but on refresh the panel doesn't keep it's state (whether open or closed). It just returns to the closed default state. I'm using a plugin for the cookies.

Comment: You might want to mention you're using a plugin. You should also post the code here. Maybe break down the problem to its components by doing a simple if/else block.

Comment: I didn't do all that because I thought the question is not complex and with one look it's pretty obvious in every angle. And also I think giving a link to Jsfiddle is much more efficient in every way. As a scientist Im always looking for ways to be transparent and clear, which means I have to simplify. Doing the the things you suggest would only complicate my question. But I do agree  I should have mentioned the plugin.

Comment: yomoore, @JohnP tried to help you by suggesting ways to improve your question in order to garner better answers. I'm down-voting the question in response to a poor question, and your disregard of suggested improvements. Also, finally, telling us that there's a "a jQuery plugin involved" doesn't help, without a link *to* that plugin.

Comment: See this meta-question on "link-only" answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle   I would say a "link-only" question falls in the same boat.

Comment: @yomoore: jsFiddle isn't the most robust site on the net.  It regularly has outages and downtime.  If someone clicks your link and they can't see the page, that might be a little frustrating.  Also, questions on Stack Overflow should be able to stand on their own and not rely on external sources such as pastebin or jsFiddle.

Comment: @yomoore posting the code here is recommended because if it's a simple fix JS coders would be able to advice you without needing to load another page. Posting a link to the fiddle is definitely recommended, but this is in addition to having all related information to your problem in the question itself. The suggestion to simplify your code was meant to help you in breaking down your code so that you can isolate your problem.

Comment: @David Thomas is allowed to give me his point of view, and so Im I. Not only do I respond giving my opinion on this matter, but also elaborate on it, something you and @JohnP lacked to do. so in contrary of what you are implying I did not disregard anything. I could have given a link to that plugin but I figured the is already on Jsfiddle, you just have to click on it to see it. Anything else..?

Comment: @yomoore "As a scientist Im always looking for ways..." - try to be more an artist than a scientist and you may easily answer you own question :) Programmers are much less scientists than artists :)

Comment: Oke, I wasn't aware of all that, Maybe I should post again..?

Comment: If it's the same question, then it's easier/better to edit the question to include the new information. Also, @yomoore, try reading this advice from [Jon Skeet: 'Writing the perfect question'](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin behavior works as expected. The problem is that you've misunderstood how the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event works.

You've given it two function arguments assuming that they will be called in alternatively to set the cookie values. Since only the second method is ever called, your state will always be `expanded`.

Also, you've set `display: none;` on the panel with your CSS, which means it won't expand even if the proper state was set. Because in your JS, you only check whether it's collapsed and hide it.

It works as expected once you fix these issues. Here's the updated code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cookie").text("expanded");

    $(".btn-slide").click(function() {
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        var state = ($.cookie('panel') != 'collapsed') ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded';
        $.cookie('panel', state);
        $("#cookie").text("collapsed");
    });

    var panel = $.cookie('panel');

    if (!panel) {
        $.cookie('panel', 'expanded');
    }

    if (panel == 'collapsed') {
        $("#panel").hide();
    } else {
        $("#panel").slideDown();
    };
});
```

And here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RJMhT/157/

Keep in mind that I haven't set a default, so for the initial loads it will be expanded. And once you've actually changed the state it will remember it.

Comment: Well what can I say...:) Thanks a lot for the time and effort. An if you felt like I was being a smartass Its just I never had down vote, It felt like an insult which it wasn't of course. In the future I will think twice before I post my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yomoore  You're welcome :) Don't take down votes personally, usually it's an indication that something needs fixing so it's better to listen to what people are saying. Most people will remove their down vote if question is improved/fixed.

Comment: That's why I upvoted the question of @yomoore. Don't know why someone just votes down instead of leaving a comment and giving a chance to reedit the question. It's not productive, just demoralizing. The Q was pretty clear.

Comment: @roXon The question wasn't actually too clear initially. Went through a few edit iterations before we got here. But yes, the DVs should usually be reviewed once the question is updated.

Answer (score 2):

HI!

Well to me the question was pretty clear!

Working Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // default:
    $("#panel").hide();
    $('#cookie').text('collapsed');

    // if cookie exist:
    if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open') {
        $('#panel').show();
        $('.slide').addClass('expanded');
        $('#cookie').text('expanded');
    }

    $(".slide").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); // toggle class
        if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) { // now we check what happend:
            $.cookie('panel', 'open', {expires: 1} ); //create cookie if .expanded is added to button
            $('#cookie').text('expanded');
        }
        else {
            $.cookie('panel', null, {expires: 1} ); // else: delete cookie
            $('#cookie').text('collapsed');
        };
        $(this).prev('#panel').slideToggle(800);
    });
});
```

**And here is a** [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJMhT/160/)

Comment: I already accepted an answer but yourse is also good. Maybe I will have to use in some other coding. Thanks.